# Style props in component in React

Tags: reactjs

I am using react to do a form. I want to style a part of the component. In this case I want to style hint. This is the component

```
<Input 
  className={this.props.className}
  ref={(input) => {this.input=input}}
  type={this.props.type}
  error={this.state.error ? this.state.errorText : ''}
  name={this.props.name}
  pattern={this.props.pattern}
  value={this.props.value}
  onBlur={this.blur}
  theme={this.theme}
  hint={this.props.hint}
  onChange={this.onChange}
  maxLength={this.props.maxLength}/>
```

anyone knows how I can style independent part of the component whilst using props.

Answer (score 2):

There's no concept of styling "part" of a component. You style an **HTML element**, like an input.

If you want to add styles to an HTML element, here are 2 examples:

```
<!-- using classes -->
<input className="myClassName" />

<!-- using styles -->
<input style={{backgroundColor: "red"}} />
```